# Values inserted through MySQLi could not be fully inserted with mysqli_insert_id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Good Day, this is just a follow-up question from [Referrence 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580043/phpmysqli-multiple-insert-error/25580096?noredirect=1#comment39987111_25580096) here on stackoverflow. Though it was now being solved partially, I still have issues with eid. The multiple insert through mysqli is a bit working (I just said a bit since only 4 our of 6 tables were being inserted with values), but when I checked if the foreign key for `eid` are also been copied by `mysqli_insert_id()` I'm surprised to see that the foreign key `eid` got 0 values.

It was like this (NOTE: The ff: data are not the actual one):

```
Table: Employee [eid is it's primary key]

eid    employee_name     address     etc
1002   employee A        Beside U     ♥
1003   employee B        Pluto        ♥

Table: Contact [eid is it's foreign key]

eid    telno         email
0      911       kingCorbra@hey.com
0      ***       universe@hey.com


Table: Work Experience [eid is it's foreign key]

eid    Company Name            start date   end date
0      Windows Macintosh       2012-12-01   2012-12-02 
0      Micro Entertainment LG  2012-12-31   2013-01-01

*Other Tables are not included in the samples but part of the query.*
```

As you know, I have used mysqli_insert_id() during the insert statement [again please see the Referrence 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580043/phpmysqli-multiple-insert-error/25580096?noredirect=1#comment39987111_25580096), and luckily it work but only for 4 out of 6 actual tables. And when I checked the eid column it shows 0 values.

Here is my select statement (not the real one):

```
` <table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><strong>Name:</strong></th>
<th><strong>Date of Birth:</strong></th>
<th><strong>Birthplace:</strong></th>
<th><strong>Gender:</strong></th>
<th><strong>Email Add:</strong></th>
<th><strong>Contact#:</strong></th>
<th><strong>Address:</strong></th>
</tr>
</thead>
    <?php
include('db.php');
    $sql=mysqli_query("SELECT emp.eid,emp.fname,
emp.mname,emp.lname,
emp.age,emp.gender,
emp.birthday,emp.birthplace,
emp.citizenship,emp.status,
emp.sss,emp.philhealth,
emp.tin,emp.height,
emp.weight,
con.address,
con.province,con.postcode,
con.telno,con.mobile,
con.email,con.alternate,
educ.elem,
educ.egrad,educ.high,
educ.hgrad,educ.college,
educ.cgrad,
ems.position,ems.hireDate,ems.job_desc,ems.basic,ems.salary,
w.company_name,w.position,w.desc,w.startDate,w.endDate,
fam.fatherName,fam.motherName,fam.sibling,fam.spouse,fam.children

 FROM employee AS emp INNER JOIN contact AS con ON con.eid='emp.eid' 

 INNER JOIN educ AS  educ ON educ.eid='emp.eid' 
 INNER JOIN employment AS  ems ON ems.eid='emp.eid'
 INNER JOIN work AS w ON w.eid='emp.eid'
 INNER JOIN family AS fam ON fam.eid='emp.eid' WHERE emp.eid='$id'");
    $counter=0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
        $cname  =   $row['name'];
        $cbday  =   $row['birthday'];
        $pob    =   $row['pob'];
        $cgen   =   $row['gender'];
        $email  =   $row['email'];
        $contact=   $row['contact'];
        $add    =   $row['address'];

            if($counter%2)
            {
            ?>
            <tbody>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <td><?php echo $cname; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cbday; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $pob; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cgen; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contract; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $add; ?></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        <?php
        $counter++;
        }//while-end
        ?>

</table>`
```

To make things much weird, let me tell you that when I tried to display values using mysqli_fetched_assoc() the query doesn't seem to work as in on my index page nothing else displays. Though the db has its record. But when I used mysql [though many have claimed it to be deprecated] it seems to work fine eventhough I had mysqli used for the insert statement. You guys get my point right? I used mysqli for insert statement and mysql for display and it works fine except for the `eid` of course.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql=mysql_query
```

Will never ever work with

```
mysqli_insert_id
     ^
```

You need to use the same API for both calls. Use `MySQLi` throughout.

Comment: I see. But even that didn't work. :( So I guess the one that has an issue here is the `mysqli_insert_id` But I couldn't think of anything else that causes its downfall.

Comment: Nope theres no issue with that. It could be how you run that function and your query. Your PHP code will help us debug that

Comment: thanks sir hanky. But is it the way I use the insert statement brought this whole mess?

Comment: How do we know that If you don't show us your PHP code to see how you execute those? :)

Comment: I thought I included the referrence on my question above... here's how I declare and execute the insert statement. [referrence 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580043/phpmysqli-multiple-insert-error/25580096?noredirect=1#comment39987111_25580096)